# vim search regular expression replace with register

Tags: regex, perl, vim

I'd like to search a regex pattern with vim and replace the matches with a paste from a register. In detail that means:

```
acb123acb
asokqwdad
def442ads
asduiosdf
df567hjk
```

should finish with

```
acbXYZacb
asokqwdad
defPOWads
asduiosdf
dafMANhjk
```

where I had

```
XYZ
POW
MAN
```

in a register A (:g/pattern/y A)

A regex pattern to search for might be [0-9]{3} to match the 3 numbers from the text block.

Block mode would help if there were no lines between the matches...

I could use a perl script therefore of course. However I'm sure, if possible in vim it were a lot faster, right?

Thank you in advance

Comment: *"if possible in vim it were a lot faster [than Perl], right?"* Wrong. Perl is almost certainly very much faster than Vim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to replace all strings matching `[0-9]{3}` with the same value, which happens to be the contents of register `a`:

```
:%s/\v\d{3}/\=@a/g
```

In detail:

- `:%` - apply to all lines in buffer
- `s/.../.../g` - replace all occurrences
- `\v` - what follows is a "very magic" regular expression
- `\d{3}` - match 3 digits
- `\=` - replace with the value of...
- `@a` - register `a`

If on the other hand you want to read replacement values from register `a`:

```
:let a=getreg('a', 1, 1)
:%s/\v\d{3}/\=remove(a, 0)/g
```

In detail:

- `let a=getreg('a', 1, 1)` - transfer the contents of register `a` to a list, imaginatively also named `a`
- then same as above, except...
- `remove(a, 0)` - deletes the first element in list `a` and returns it.

Also, VimL is, sadly, nowhere near as fast as Perl. :)

Comment: Thank you so far. Actually the second task was what I intended to do. When I use the getreg()-function as suggested, I still get the E118: Too many arguments for function: getreg. However, I'm confident that it would work this way. I wrote a perl-script now, which took some time... Do you still think perl is faster for my task? (I didn't mean "faster" w.r.t. the final execution but w.r.t. its implementation) ;)

Comment: The exact arguments of `getreg()` might depend on Vim version, I only tried it with 7.4.703.  As for Perl-thinking being faster than Vim-thinking, I'd say it is.  Unless you happen to maintain a few Vim plugins or some such (which basically force you to know the details of VimL inside out), VimL is just insane. _shrug_

Comment: Where can I find documentation on `\=`? vimregex.com only says that it "matches 0 or 1 more of the preceding characters"